# How to stop a thread and restart it - python

Tags: python

How can I stop a thread from running and then restart it when called, havent been able to get a solid answer on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you finished the thread, you can not get the same thread back. If you just want to synchronize that thread with e.g. main thread use synchronization primitives like Condition, Event, Semaphore etc. Show your code to show what you want to achieve.

Comment: You can't literally stop an restart thread, because when a thread is stopped, it's gone. You can, however start a new thread that will continue the task, or use a mutex to block a running thread.

Comment: A bit more context as to why you want to do this and what you're trying to accomplish would be nice.

Comment: A thread doesn’t work like a car. Can you tell us why do you think you need to restart a thread?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html), currently, [...], threads cannot be destroyed, stopped, suspended, resumed, or interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

thread must terminate from the outside ,Python doesn’t give you this ability, and thus forces you to design your thread systems more carefully. This recipe is based on the idea of a thread whose main function uses a loop. Periodically, the loop checks if a threading.Event object has been set. If so, the thread terminates; otherwise, it waits for the object.

**The answer is:** You don’t. Instead, you kindly ask it to go away. The thread must periodically check if it’s been asked to go away and then comply (typically after some kind of clean-up)